# Where does port put its installs in osx?

Tags: python, macos, classpath, port

I have installed scipy with port on my mac.  it says all is fine:

```
$ sudo port install py-scipy
Password:
--->  Computing dependencies for py-scipy
--->  Cleaning py-scipy
```

but when i pull up python, it doesn't see it:

```
$ python2.6
Python 2.6.7 (r267:88850, Jul 27 2011, 11:54:59) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named scipy
```

My path includes the port locations i've been able to find online:

```
... '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python26.zip', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg-info', ...
```

In fact I can't find scipy files installed anywhere along the /opt/local/Library/Frameworks etc path.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

To change your current version of Python to the one installed with MacPorts:

`sudo port select python python26`

This should let you use the MacPorts version of Python that has scipy installed.

Answer (score 0):

For more information search for `macports.conf`, you will have all the information there. You can also `man macports.conf` for some details.

Answer (score 0):

The Python module that you installed isn't in the search path of the standard OS X version of Python. When you install a Python module using MacPorts it will install it's own version of Python. You can start using MacPort's version using the `select` command:

```
sudo port select python python26
```

Another option is to install it using the standard Python easy_install